# How to output my JSONObject, but nicer with different lines and indentation?

Tags: java, json

I am using Java and I have:

```
Boolean happiness;

JSONObject happyJSON = new JSONObject();

happyJSON.put("happy", happiness);
```

-

So right now, when the boolean is true, my output (in a jsonfile) looks like this:

```
{"happiness":true}
```

But I am trying to output it like this:

```
{
       "happiness":true
}
```

On three different lines, with the proper indentation. Thank you for your advice.